# Restrict system.log logging to particular error level?

Tags: error, magento-1, log, logging

By default Magento logs notices, warnings and errors into the `system.log` file. Is it possible to restrict the log level so that Magento doesn't log PHP notices?

Magento's `Mage::log()` method offers the option to set the log level by providing, e.g. `Zend_Log::DEBUG` as a parameter, and it'd be great to suppress logging of PHP notices.

ps. I do know that fixing the code producing the errors would be recommended, but the errors originate from third-party code and extensions, so that'd be impossible to manage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you'd like to set the level to `Zend_Log::WARN`, according to `Zend_Log`:

```
const EMERG   = 0;  // Emergency: system is unusable
const ALERT   = 1;  // Alert: action must be taken immediately
const CRIT    = 2;  // Critical: critical conditions
const ERR     = 3;  // Error: error conditions
const WARN    = 4;  // Warning: warning conditions
const NOTICE  = 5;  // Notice: normal but significant condition
const INFO    = 6;  // Informational: informational messages
const DEBUG   = 7;  // Debug: debug messages
```

As I see you cannot and won't go through the 3rd party code and set this globally, you could try to adjust the PHP error reporting this way:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

I didn't test it but maybe it helps to get rid of the entries in the log.

Comment: Adding `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` to the index.php file did work. Easier than expected, but since the PHP notices originated from Apache, that's the way to go without having to modify third-party code.

Answer (score 2):

For advanced logging capabilities, take a look at https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Logger

Comment: Which has moved to Firegento Logger: https://github.com/firegento/firegento-logger

Comment: both outdated / not existing anymore (2016)

Comment: The second isn't? https://github.com/firegento/firegento-logger