# how to ignore Notice and warning in system.log?

Tags: magento-1.9, system.log

I am using `Magento 1.9.2`. I need to `disable warning and notice` in a `system.log` file.

Comment: you have disable log via admin

Answer (score 0):

You can modify error_reporting variable in php.ini as below

> error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE

Also this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7450/restrict-system-log-logging-to-particular-error-level) may help you

Answer (score 0):

Try with below way

Add below code in `index.php` file.

> error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

Take reference from [Anna Völkl](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7450/restrict-system-log-logging-to-particular-error-level) Answer.

**Note :** I did't test above code. it may help you.